# How to write constraints for this tricky LP or MIP program?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research, mixed-integer-programming

I have order quantities as decision variables. How do I write constraints adding up the orders with different lead times and arriving in a single period?

[image: Orders and Lead Time]

Comment: Are lead times constant, or are they also variables?

Comment: The lead times are constant for this problem. The reason I varied them a bit is because  I was looking for an answer which is generic and not specifically  designed for lead times 0,1 and 2 for air, land sea respectively.

Comment: I figured this problem(https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B74iryIUAeIwT0lTUjhoazJEX2M) but I have a feeling I may have complicated it a bit. I welcome any solutions better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Let $m$ denote the transportation mode (air, sea or land), $t$ the time the order is placed, and $x_{mt}$ the amount shipped via mode $m$ at time $t$. Let $\ell_{mt}$ be the lead time for an order shipped at time $t$ via mode $m$. Importantly, I'm assuming lead times are parameters rather than variables. Then the total quantity due for delivery in period $\tau$ is $\sum_m \sum_{t : t + \ell_{m t} = \tau} x_{m, t}$.

Comment: Sir, could you help me with this [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3593506/how-to-write-a-mixed-integer-program-for-a-streak)